# MSTP - different VLAN mapping in different regions

Tags: cisco, switching, spanning-tree, ieee-802.1s

Regarding MSTP, is it possible to have different VLAN mapping for different regions ?

Example: 
Region 1:
Instance 1: VLAN 10,20,30
Instance 2: VLAN 40,50,60

Region 2:
Instance 1: VLAN 10,50,60
Instance 2: VLAN 20,30,40

Also I read in Cisco press CCNP references: "VLANs are grouped into an instance, and each instance elects a root bridge."

So you confirm that inside a region, we have one root bridge per instance ? So inside a region we could have different root bridge for different instances ?

So in conclusion inside a region composed of three bridge for example, A, B and C, A could be the root bridge for the IST (instance 0), B could be the root bridge for the instance 1 and C the root bridge for the instance 2 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Regarding MSTP, is it possible to have different VLAN mapping for
>   different regions ?
>
> Example: Region 1: Instance 1: VLAN 10,20,30 Instance 2: VLAN 40,50,60
>
> Region 2: Instance 1: VLAN 10,50,60 Instance 2: VLAN 20,30,40

Yes, see [catalyst 3560 config guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/12-2_52_se/configuration/guide/3560scg/swmstp.html):

> The MSTP enables multiple VLANs to be mapped to the same spanning-tree
>   instance, reducing the number of spanning-tree instances needed to
>   support a large number of VLANs.

Regarding:

> So you confirm that inside a region, we have one root bridge per instance ? So inside a region we could have different root bridge for
>   different instances ?
>
> So in conclusion inside a region composed of three bridge for example,
>   A, B and C, A could be the root bridge for the IST (instance 0), B
>   could be the root bridge for the instance 1 and C the root bridge for
>   the instance 2 ?

Correct, each MST instance has its own topology parameters.

I know you tagged Cisco, but if someone from Juniper also needs to check for their wording: [Understanding MSTP for EX Series and QFX Series Switches](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/spanning-trees-ex-series-mstp-understanding.html)

> An MSTP region can support up to 64 MSTIs,, and each MSTI can support
>   from 1 to 4094 VLANs. When you define a region, MSTP automatically
>   creates an internal spanning-tree instance (IST instance 0) that
>   provides the root switch for the region and includes all currently
>   configured VLANs that are not specifically assigned to a user-defined
>   MSTI.

Answer (score 3):

You group VLAN IDs into *instances* which each form their own spanning tree with its own root bridge. Using different instances has the advantage that some instances/groups can use links that others won't. This way, you can make use of redundant links that would be useless with a single instance.

A region is a part of the network that your instances are confined in. Spanning trees don't span across region boundaries. So, each region can do what it wants without impacting any other.